# kotlin access modifiers extending generic abstract class with internal class as generic parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics, abstract-class, persistence, access-modifiers

I am trying to implement Business objects, so i have PEmail (persistance object) class and BEmail (business interface).
And others as follows

```
class EmailImpl internal constructor(persistent: PEmail): BEmail, BBase<PEmail>(persistent)

abstract class BBase<P> internal constructor(internal val persistent:P)
```

Can't figure out how to hide the persistance objects like PEmail internally.
IDE giving me this message 'public' subclass exposes its 'internal' supertype argument Email every time i set PEmail internal.
If kotlin does not support this kind of operation what can I do to make it work? With JAVA it works well.

I tried to set PEmail internal but the only thing that seems to work is setting all properties internal in  PEmail class. But this still not solves the problem of hiding the ugly stuff, because class is still visible.

Comment: You can always make the `EmailImpl` internal as well. As a matter of fact, I usually do this anyway. If feels to me "Impl" classes are generally internal stuff.

Comment: But I though I could split my code into repository module, and make Public only repo and business classes. Maby not a big deal but i want to do it properly.

Comment: Previously i used bare interface exposure, but that required type casting, and i think it's not ideal either.

Comment: What do you mean exactly about the type casting? No matter if implementations are internal or not, ideally, we should type our code, properties, etc. against interfaces, not implementations, Otherwise, our code will be hard to test, hard to customize or adapt to changing requirements.

Comment: Object I hide behind interface while returning from repo have additional persistance val which is persistance i'm trying to hide. But after saving this object back to repo i have to check if this object have persistant val in it. I am prety sure i'm missing something.